# How to authenticate users per application in django

Tags: python, django, authentication

I have chat app in django at `http://mydomain.com/chat/` 
I want to display logged in users in the sidebar

but I don’t want users who are logged in on main site `http://mydomain.com` which is different app

how can i do this
or if its not possible is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm considering that both the apps are in the same project and you are using a common authentication module for the same. (django.contrib.auth?)

Inherit the user model to create a new model say myuser.

```
class MyUser(User):
 isChatUser=BooleanField(default=False)
```

Alternatively you can use a charField with choices.

Now you'll have to show users who are authenticated and are registered as chat users.

```
def isChatUserLoggedIn(user):
 if user.is_authenticated():
  try:
   myuser = MyUser.objects.get(id=user.id)
   return (True if myuser.isChatUser else False)
  except:
   return False
#And then use the following when verifying your user-->
isChatUserLoggedIn(request.user)
```

I hope this was useful.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is not the best approach. But database routers would do the trick: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/.
it allows you to have multiple databases(thus, multiple auth systems). And use different databases with the app currently being executed.

As an alternative, you can extend the User model to create a new column a rewrite the auth system to check if the user that is trying to login is the user that's registered in it's repective application.

Comment: Both apps belongs to the same project. He shouldn't bother to create multiple databases. The answer given by @Arpit is the good approach.

Comment: @sachitad yeah, my second paragraph says the same thing but shorter.